# Receiving access violation error on fgets() in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io

I am getting access violation error when I run the following code on Visual studio. Perhaps I am trying to read some pointer location that I have not allocated or something, But I cannot seem to find where the problem exactly is. Need some help with the same.

```
#include <iostream>

class fileReader
{
public:
    FILE *fp;
    char** lines;
    fileReader()
    {
        fp = NULL;
    }
    fileReader(char* path)
    {
        int j=0;
        fp = fopen(path,"r");
        if (fp == NULL) 
            return;
        else 
        {
            lines = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char *)*56000);
            for (int i=0; i<56000; i++)
                lines[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1440);
            while ( fgets(lines[j], 1440, fp) )
                j++;
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    char* path = "D:\\testfile.txt";
    fileReader *p = new fileReader(path);
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        std::cout<<p->lines[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no protection on `j` exceeding number of elements in `lines`:

```
while ( fgets(lines[j], 1440, fp) )
    j++;
```

If file contains more that `56000` lines, then this will access beyond the bounds of the array.

As this is C++, you should consider using `ifstream`, `std::getline()` and `std::vector<std::string>` to read the file. `std::vector<std::string>` will manage the memory allocation for you:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::ifstream in("D:\\testfile.txt");

if (in.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: An error I missed.  There are enough errors in his code to trigger any number of errors.  The first one that struck me was what happens if the `fopen` fails.  Your proposed solution is a major step in the right direction: most of the errors he's making either can't happen, or can't be ignored, using the appropriate tools.

Comment: @JamesKanze, good spot on `fopen()` failure (+1'd your answer) as it does not affect the flow of `main()`, it still uses `lines`.

Comment: Well, as I said, there are enough errors to go around.  I thought I'd caught them all, but I'd missed the one you spotted.  The uninitialized pointers if the `fopen` fails, the null pointers if `malloc` fails, or the buffer overflow if the file contains too many lines will all likely result in a crash.  The fact that he never frees any memory will make reuse of the class very problematic.  And of course, any user would like to know if the writes failed, and probably if the file couldn't be opened.

Comment: @JamesKanze, plus absence of copy constructor and assignment operator with dynamically allocated members.

Comment: And just for the record: your loop doesn't do quite the same thing as his.  `fgets` puts the `'\n'` in the buffer, `getline` doesn't.  (From extensive experience in both C++ and Python---whose library routines do put the `'\n'` in the buffer---I'd generally prefer your version.  Even if I did add the `'\n'` in my answer, to be compatible with what he was doing.)

Comment: Good point too, although in this case, I think I'd just inherit from `boost::noncopyable`.  (But it's one or the other: either the class copies correctly, or it's not copyable.)

Answer (score 2):

You're not checking the return value of `malloc`:

```
 lines = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char *)*56000);
 for (int i=0; i<56000; i++)
     lines[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1440);
```

If `malloc` fails, it returns `NULL`.

And you're attempting to allocate quite a bit of memory, so I'd start there.

Comment: It's only a little more than 80MBytes, so on most modern general purpose machines, it should be OK.  Still, not checking the return value of `malloc` is an error, always (since who knows what else might be using memory on your machine).  And not freeing the memory when he's through with the object (in the destructor) isn't a good idea either.  One wonders why he's even bothered to use a class, rather than a free function.  Not to mention what happens if the `fopen` fails.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if the `fopen` fails?  I see some uninitialized pointers
floating around in this case.  And in the unlikely case that `malloc`
fails, you're going to have some null pointers, which shouldn't be
dereferenced.  And you don't ensure that at least two lines were 
actually read before you do the loop in `main`; if there weren't, you're
going to try to output uninitialized data.  Not to mention the fact that
you never free the memory you allocate.

(FWIW: using your strategy, `j` should be public, but `fp` can be local
to `FileReader::FileReader`.)

An almost exact equivalent to this would be to use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > lines;
//  ...
FileReader( char const* path )
    : lines( 56000, std::vector<char>( 1440 ) ) 
{
    //  ...
}
```

The only difference would be the call to `fgets`, which would have to be
`fgets( &lines[j][0], lines[j].size(), fp )`.

I'd probably prefer using an `std::vector<std::string>`, initialized
empty, and then doing a pushback for each line read:

```
FileReader( char const* path )
{
    std::ifstream input( path );
    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
        lines.push_back( line + '\n' );
    }
}
```

Much, much simpler, and it solves most of the problems you encounter.
(In practice, I'ld probably check if the file was correctly opened
separately; it's generally nice to give an error message if you can't
open an input, rather than treating it like an empty file.)

And of course, there's no reason to use `new` in `main`.  Just:

```
int
main()
{
    FileReader file( "D:/testfile.txt" );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != file.lines.size(); ++ i ) {
        std::cout << file.lines[i];
    }
    return std::cout.flush() ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```